# read CSV in Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii, fgetcsv

I am reading a csv file in yii framework. it loops through every word in the file but saves only last word. For example i have following words in my csv file.

```
First
Second
Third
Fourth
```

following is my code which loops through the file.

```
$fileHandler=fopen("upload.csv",'r');
       if($fileHandler){
         while($line=fgetcsv($fileHandler,1000)){
           $model->image_url=$line[0];
                $model->save();
        }
    }
```

it is only saving value 'Fourth' in my db. Please guide.

Comment: Won't it be working correctly, but instead of inserting, updating all the time the same row? That would explain why you only see the last line.

Comment: you need to initialize the $model with in the loop.. @Chococroc is right

Comment: @zzlalani, add an answer with it, I have no idea of how YII works, so, you deserve the merit of the answer, ;D

Comment: Welldone @Chococroc You are right. I have seen so many tutorials of reading csv with above flow of code no one had reinitialized the model within the loop. Thanks. Hats Off

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Chococroc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1168804/chococroc) suggested in the comments, You need to initialize your `$model` with in the loop rather of out side, since it has saved the value in the first iteration and then updating the same object (i.e. same row in your database) for the rest of the iterations

```
$fileHandler=fopen("upload.csv",'r');
if($fileHandler){
   while($line=fgetcsv($fileHandler,1000)){
      $model = new CLASS_NAME;
      $model->image_url=$line[0];
      $model->save();
   }
}
```